# Need meta-programming magic to define a mother lode of bit fields in an error-free way

Tags: c++, macros, metaprogramming, bit-fields

The goal is to control which types of users are allowed to perform which operations at the UI level. This code has been in place for a while; I just want to improve it a bit.
The file which I am trying to improve should probably be auto-generated, but that would be too big of a change, so I seek a simpler solution.

A file which we shall call `PermissionBits.h` has a bunch of these:

```
// Here names are mangled; for example XYZ_OP_A is:
// permission to operation A in category/context XYZ
// SCU64 = static const unsigned __int64
// Some namespaces utilize all 64 bits
// The actual values (as long as they are proper bit fields) 
// do not matter - they are always used by name
namespace XYZPermissionBits
{
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_A = 1UI64 <<  0; //    1 = 0x0000000000000001
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_B = 1UI64 <<  1; //    2 = 0x0000000000000002
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_C = 1UI64 <<  2; //    4 = 0x0000000000000004
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_C = 1UI64 <<  3; //    8 = 0x0000000000000008
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_D = 1UI64 <<  4; //   16 = 0x0000000000000010
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_E = 1UI64 <<  5; //   32 = 0x0000000000000020
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_F = 1UI64 <<  6; //   64 = 0x0000000000000040
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_G = 1UI64 <<  7; //  128 = 0x0000000000000080
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_H = 1UI64 <<  8; //  256 = 0x0000000000000100
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_I = 1UI64 <<  9; //  512 = 0x0000000000000200
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_J = 1UI64 << 10; // 1024 = 0x0000000000000400
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_K = 1UI64 << 11; // 2048 = 0x0000000000000800
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_L = 1UI64 << 12; // 4096 = 0x0000000000001000 
}
```

Even with the help of `1UI64 << <numBits>;` shortcut there are still problems, as coders create flags with duplicate values, make typos, etc.

Ideally I would like a macro which can be nicely formatted and look like:

```
BITFIELDS_FOR_NAMESPACE(
    //*************** <<== I want to make the namespace name more vivid
    XYZPermissionBits,
    //*************** <<== somehow if that is possible. It is not a must-have.
    XYZ_OP_A, // Being able to add a comment here would be nice, but not critical
    XYZ_OP_B,
    XYZ_OP_C,
    XYZ_OP_D,
    XYZ_OP_E,
    XYZ_OP_F,
    XYZ_OP_G,
    XYZ_OP_H,
    XYZ_OP_I,
    XYZ_OP_J,
    XYZ_OP_K,
    XYZ_OP_L
)
```

I would like this macro be flexible and prevent me from entering less than 2 or more than 65 arguments - namespace name + 64 flags. Is it possible to do what I want or close to it, or should I resort to generated code? What other advice do you have?

Comment: One thing I do have to say in *favor* of nailing down the values of each permission separately, as in your first snippet, is that it reduces the chance of those values changing if say someone repurposes a permission or decides to get rid of one. If you're storing flags in a database, that can be a very important consideration.

Comment: BTW I noticed that in you first code snippet you have XYZ_OP_C defined twice.  I presume this is a deliberate error to show how fragile doing it by hand can be.  ;)

Comment: @Dave, haha, no, I tried to get it right and messed up while asking this question. I pasted actual code and then renamed stuff just in case and to make it fit on a page better. I will leave it as is unless many object. The copy-and-paste problem is real. It's not just unclean by academic standards, it actually bites :)

Comment: I've really got to ask, if you need this many, it's a hint that constants are not the right way to go. Especially alphabetical ones like this. Why on earth do you actually need this?

Comment: "Alphabetical constants like this" are not actually being used. It is easy to overlook, but the question mentions this. I try to share as little actual code as possible, even if it stinks. I have entertained myself with the idea of a complete rewrite, but that will not happen; the best I can do is try to improve an old beast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested example using Boost.PreProcessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/greater.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/less.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/debug/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/size.hpp>

#define CHECK_SIZE(size) \
  BOOST_PP_ASSERT_MSG(BOOST_PP_GREATER(size, 1), "<  2 :(") \
  BOOST_PP_ASSERT_MSG(BOOST_PP_LESS(size, 65),   "> 64 :(") \

#define DO_MAKE_BITFIELDS(a, b, i, elem) \
  SCU64 elem = 1UI64 << i;

#define BITFIELDS_FOR_NAMESPACE(name, seq) \
  CHECK_SIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(seq)) \
  namespace name { \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DO_MAKE_BITFIELDS, _, seq) \
  }
```

Usage:

```
BITFIELDS_FOR_NAMESPACE(
    XYZPermissionBits,
    (XYZ_OP_A)
    (XYZ_OP_B)
    // ...
);
```

Comment: if you could actually test this, it would be so awesome!

Comment: Thanks, just one clarification: why do you need a comma after a namespace name but not after flag names? Are parenthesis also defined as macros :)?

Comment: @Ham: The namespace name is the first argument, the comma seperates it from the second argument: all the parantheses-enclosed flag names form one argument and are a [sequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html), which can then be processed with the `BOOST_PP_SEQ_*`.

Comment: @Ham: Added a short [blog post](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/07/boost-preprocessors-sequences/) on those sequences if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

IFAIK, The boost preprocessor library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html has all the primitives you need.

Comment: An example would be great. Can I just steal a header file from that library, or do I have to install something? Is it still a standard preprocessor or some other magic? I am using VS2010 on Windows.

Comment: Without Boost Preprocessor, it would take a large amount of nearly-identical macros, which would be even more error prone than your original problem unless you used code generation to create them...

Comment: Boost Preprocessor is entirely implemented with headers. You should be able to incorporate them directly into your project, but Boost has so many other goodies it may be worth keeping the whole thing around.

Comment: @cog, about your second comment - so ... what is different about boost preprocessor? Would not it have to create thousands of Macros, or that's how it is done, with the exception that these macros have been in use and heavily tested?

Comment: @Hamish, boost is standard code.  While it sometimes push the compilers to their limits it often contains work around or offer simply degraded functionalities for non conforming compilers, especially mainline one.  And I don't think that part is pushing the limits very hard, it is just tedious code.

Comment: @Hamish, your intuition is correct. If you take a look at the boost code, it's incredibly tedious. It's been around quite a while and is well-tested though, so by using it you're taking advantage of all that already-invested time.

Answer (score 2):

If you do decide to go the code generation route then I suggest taking a look at [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/).

Cog lets you embed python code as comments in the C++ (or any other language) source file, and when run through Cog the python output is inserted as source code, so the generator code and generated output are all managed in the same file.  This keeps maintenance simple. and the python code documents how the generated code was created.

Here is your example using cog, including the generated code:

```
namespace XYZPermissionBits
{
    /* [[[cog
    import cog
    operations = ["A", "B", "C", "D", 
                  "E", "F", "G", "H",
                  "I", "J", "K", "L"]

    assert 2 <= len(operations) <= 64

    for idx,op in enumerate(operations):
        cog.outl("SCU64 XYZ_OP_%s = 1UI64 << %s;" % (op, idx))

    ]]] */
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_A = 1UI64 << 0;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_B = 1UI64 << 1;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_C = 1UI64 << 2;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_D = 1UI64 << 3;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_E = 1UI64 << 4;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_F = 1UI64 << 5;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_G = 1UI64 << 6;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_H = 1UI64 << 7;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_I = 1UI64 << 8;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_J = 1UI64 << 9;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_K = 1UI64 << 10;
    SCU64 XYZ_OP_L = 1UI64 << 11;
// [[[end]]]
}
```

Comment: Wait, what you posted is a union of source and result, or is cog "self-modifying", if that makes sense?

Comment: @Hamish:  yes, cog is self modifying as you put it - the cog output includes both the original file contents and the generated code.  See the cog documentation at the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of macros/preprocessors/etc I'd stick with a static text file similar to the original.  It seems much easier to understand and expand or maintain.  I might define each value as a shift of the previous value, but that might seem more confusing to some readers.  To help prevent typos by users, I'd probably use a more verbose abbreviation for each "op" instead of A, B, C (defined twice), D...

Comment: @Hamish:  1000 flags!  is it logically just every possible combination of operation and context?  perhaps editing your original question into a more complete description of the who/what/when/where/why/how of your system will let someone suggest an even better design or solution...

Comment: Just a very large system with barely any combination to generalize. Let's just say we use http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=authorization+manager&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=authorization+manager&gs_rfai=&fp=76b50334b16c878d, and for historical reasons employ lots of bit fields and MFC serialization under multi-tier architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this.  Create a macro called MAKE_THINGS that looks like:

```
#define MAKE_THINGS \
  MAKE_THING(NAME1) \
  MAKE_THING(NAME2) \
  MAKE_THING(NAME3) \
  /* Include semantically-blank line after list */
```

One can then define MAKE_THING, start a declaration, call MAKE_THINGS, end the declaration, and undefine MAKE_THING.  If desired, each thing can include more than one attribute:

For example:

```
#define MAKE_THINGS \
  MAKE_THING(HAPPY,"Happy") \
  MAKE_THING(SAD_AND_BLUE,"Sad and blue") \
  MAKE_THING(SLEEPY,"Sleepy") \
  /* Include semantically-blank line after list */

#define MAKE_THING(x,y) NUMBER_##x,
typedef enum {MAKE_THINGS LAST_THING} THING_NUMBER;
#undef MAKE_THING

#define MAKE_THING(x,y) FLAG_##x = (1L << NUMBER##x),
typedef enum {MAKE_THINGS ALL_FLAGS = (1 << LAST_THING)-1} THING_FLAGS;
#undef MAKE_THING

#define MAKE_THING(x,y) const char *MSG_##x = y;
MAKE_THINGS
#undef MAKE_THING

#define MAKE_THING(x,y) MSG_##x,
const char *thing_names[] = {MAKE_THINGS 0};
#undef MAKE_THING
```

Note that all of the declarations are automatically kept parallel.  Each thing gets a number (0..N-1), an flag (bit corresponding to its number), a message string, and a place in an array of message strings.